# Logging everything a program does

Tags: anti-virus, logging

I am creating a virtual machine that is equipped to test fishy .exe files. Is there such a program that allows you to see exactly what files a .exe is creating or things such as processes it is spawning. I know there are online services which you can use to scan files which will produce such reports, but are there programs out there to also accomplish this?

Comment: [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: As Sathya mentioned above, nothing better than Process Monitor, Process Explorer and [related apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533).

Comment: You should be aware that there is no guarantee that a "fishy" file cannot find its way out of a virtual machine and onto the host machine.

Comment: @Ramhound my hope is that using a combination of a sandbox and a virtual machine will allow it to stay isolated.